# Matching each function to each element

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Assume that you have two lists of the same size where 
1st contains functions for ex. 
`{u,i,o,p}`
2nd contains numbers for ex. 
`{1,2,3,4}`.
Create list such that each function is matched to each element:
`{u[1], i[2], o[3], p[4]}`

Comment: Something like `MapThread[#1[#2] &,
 {{u, i, o, p}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]` will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Compose @@@ Transpose[{{u, i, o, p}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]
Inner[Compose, {u, i, o, p}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, List]
MapThread[Compose, {{u, i, o, p}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]
Module[{t = Thread[{##}]}, t[[All, 0]] = #@#2 &; t] &[{u, i, o, p}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

all give

> {u[1], i[2], o[3], p[4]}

You can use `#@#2&` in place of `Compose` above to get the same results.

Also, for fun,

```
☺ = # @ #2 & @@@ ({##}) &;
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
☺[{u, i, o, p}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> {u[1], i[2], o[3], p[4]}

Comment: Is `# @ #2 & @@@ ({##}T) &;` the same as `#1[#2] & @@@ Transpose[##]&`?

Comment: @IshouldchangemyUsername, almost. You need to change `Transpose[##]` to `Transpose[{##}]`.

Answer (score 3):

This will also work:
`Transpose[{{u, i, o, p}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}] /. {x_Symbol, y_Integer} -> x[y]`